# Can I add environment variables to a React Native app after it's built?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, continuous-integration, devops

I have a React Native app which has some environment variables (mostly API urls). Because of my development workflow, often I need to build a new version of the app where the only change is to these environment variables.

It takes about 50min to build the iOS app on GitHub Actions.  I'm looking for a way to speed this up.  Is it possible for me to somehow cache the build without the environment variables and inject those later?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use Firebase Remote config.

This link https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config.

you can create a different layout or settings files, and select from the app which one you want to use when it loads.